# How to fix that white flikering behind keyboard in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was tying to make a whatsapp clone

Tried to fix this issue by changing inputSoftmode inside the AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

Comment: Wrap your outermost component inside a View, give it a flex of 1 and change the background color of that view to your desired color. That will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo try expo-system-ui and set background color. It worked for me!